# Creating struct using pointer

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, addition, singly-linked-list

Im working on a program that creates a structure with functions for adding and displaying new nodes. I have a function called "add" and I use it to create new nodes and send them to struct->next but whenever I try to run my function "displayData", the function says that my structure is NULL/empty.

Here is the code.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct node *nodePtr;
    struct node {
    int item;
    nodePtr next;
    };
    typedef nodePtr Statistician;

    int input();
    Statistician newStatistician();     //allocates memory to the structure.                 Dynamic allocation
    void add(Statistician s, int x);    //Adds data to the rear
    void displayData(Statistician s);   //prints entire dataset

    int main() {

        int operation, data;
        Statistician s = NULL;

        data = input();                 //get new input
        add(s,data);                    //run add function
        displayData(s);                 //run display function
    }

    int input(){
        int x;
        printf("Enter data: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &x) != 1)
        {
            printf("\n\nInvalid Input!\n\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        return x;
    }

    Statistician newStatistician(){
        Statistician newStat;
        newStat = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        return newStat;
    }

    void add(Statistician s, int x){
        Statistician newNode = newStatistician();
        newNode->item = x;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        if(s == NULL){
             s = newNode;
             return;
        }
        while (s != NULL) {
            s = s->next;
        }
        s->next = newNode;  
    }

    void displayData(Statistician s){
         Statistician temp = s;
         if(s==NULL){
            printf("\n\nList is EMPTY.");
            printf( "\n\nPress any key.\n" );
            getch();
            return;
         }
        printf( "\n\nThe List:\n" );
        while (temp != NULL) {
            printf(" %d", temp->item);
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        printf( "\n\nPress any key.\n" );
        getch();
        return;
    }
```

When i use displayData, the output is.

```
       List is EMPTY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the head node by reference. Otherwise the functions that change the list will deal with a copy of the head node and the original head node will not be changed.

For example

```
void add(Statistician *s, int x)
{
    Statistician newNode = newStatistician();
    newNode->item = x;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    while ( *s != NULL ) s = &( *s )->next;

    *s = newNode;
}
```

And the function can be called like

```
add( &s, data );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!